# Doing compatible VSIX Project for VS 2015 and VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I have a VSIX project implemented for VS 2015. I follow this link to migrate a vsix project to VS 2017:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017

I changed the value of the xml tag MinimumVisualStudioVersion in the VSIX `csproj` file from 14.0 to 15.0. But now I can not open the project in VS 2015.

I can migrate the project. The problem is that after the migration I can not open the VSIX project in VS 2015. I would like to configure the VSIX project so that it remains compatible for VS 2015 and VS 2017.

In my develop team we are working with the two VS versions. That's why I need to have the project configured for 2015 and 2017. I would like to have one `csproj` file for the two VS versions and not two csproj files. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: One thing is you shouldn't change the MinimumVisualStudioVersion, obviously. And I'm not sure you want to "migrate" anything unless mandatory.

Comment: Right. Actually it is correct to indicat that MinimumVisualStudioVersion is 14.0. But if I don't change the value to 15.0 I can not load the project in VS 2017. It says "needs migrated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question you really have two issues: How do open the `.csproj` in the both vs 2015 and vs 2017 and how to build the vsix for both of them?

To allow opening in the both of Visual studio versions you can add to the `.csproj` something likes this:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0' Or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '15.0' ">
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>$(VisualStudioVersion)</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

To allow build vsix for both of them you need to use v3 of `.vsixmanifest`, set a correct targets and prerequest and use the relevant nuget package which has the necessary tools and tasks to build vsix. More detailed information you can find in the [article from Carlos Quintero](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/01/10/its-time-to-change-the-vsix-manifest-of-your-extension-to-v3-for-visual-studio-2017-compatibility/) and in the [FAQ for vs 2017](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/faq-2017.md)